# nginx http upload module config

Tags: php, nginx, upload

I recently put nginx in front of apache to act as a reverse proxy.

Up until now Apache handled directly the requests and file uploads

Now, I need to configure nginx so that it sends file upload requests to apache.

I have several endpoints for uploading files and I am trying to see if there is a quick way to define one configuration options in nginx for all my endpoints

Right now the below refers just to one file upload entry

```
location /banner_upload {
    proxy_pass  http://backend:8080/banner/save;
   }




 location /banner/save {
            # Pass altered request body to this location
            upload_pass /banner_upload;

        # Store files to this directory
        # The directory is hashed, subdirectories 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 should exist
        upload_store /tmp 1;

        # Allow uploaded files to be read only by user
        #upload_store_access user:r;

        # Set specified fields in request body
        upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_name" $upload_file_name;
        upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_content_type" $upload_content_type;
        upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_path" $upload_tmp_path;

        # Inform backend about hash and size of a file
        upload_aggregate_form_field "${upload_field_name}_md5" $upload_file_md5;
        upload_aggregate_form_field "${upload_field_name}_size" $upload_file_size;

        upload_pass_form_field "(.*)";
    }
```

But the above entry is just for 1 endpoint

I have like 7 different ones

Do I need to make a new entry foreach of my endpoints or is there a way I can group them

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this mind, but you should be able to set a named location and rewrite requests to that. You still need one line for each request though

```
#Add one of these for each location
rewrite ^/upload/location1$ @upload last;
rewrite ^/upload/location2$ @upload last;
rewrite ^/upload/location3$ @upload last;
rewrite ^/upload/location4$ @upload last;

location = @upload {
        # Pass altered request body to this location
        upload_pass /banner_upload;

        # Store files to this directory
        # The directory is hashed, subdirectories 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 should exist
        upload_store /tmp 1;

        # Allow uploaded files to be read only by user
        #upload_store_access user:r;

        # Set specified fields in request body
        upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_name" $upload_file_name;
        upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_content_type" $upload_content_type;
        upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_path" $upload_tmp_path;

        # Inform backend about hash and size of a file
        upload_aggregate_form_field "${upload_field_name}_md5" $upload_file_md5;
        upload_aggregate_form_field "${upload_field_name}_size" $upload_file_size;
        
        upload_pass_form_field "(.*)";
}
```

That's the rough idea, I might have got some of the syntax wrong so consult the wiki if you get issues.

#### Edit

Depending on the rest of your config, you might have better luck rewriting to a directory

```
#Add one of these for each location
rewrite ^/upload/location1$ /upload/ last;
rewrite ^/upload/location2$ /upload/ last;
rewrite ^/upload/location3$ /upload/ last;
rewrite ^/upload/location4$ /upload/ last;

location /upload/ {
        # Pass altered request body to this location
        upload_pass /banner_upload;

        # Store files to this directory
        # The directory is hashed, subdirectories 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 should exist
        upload_store /tmp 1;

        # Allow uploaded files to be read only by user
        #upload_store_access user:r;

        # Set specified fields in request body
        upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_name" $upload_file_name;
        upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_content_type" $upload_content_type;
        upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_path" $upload_tmp_path;

        # Inform backend about hash and size of a file
        upload_aggregate_form_field "${upload_field_name}_md5" $upload_file_md5;
        upload_aggregate_form_field "${upload_field_name}_size" $upload_file_size;
        
        upload_pass_form_field "(.*)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to group all your endpoints into an "alias":

```
  upstream backend_pool {
      server 10.0.0.1:8080;
      server 10.0.0.2:8080;
      server 10.0.0.3:8080;
  }

  location /banner_upload {
      proxy_pass  http://backend_pool/banner/save;
  }
```

More about that here:

http://wiki.nginx.org/LoadBalanceExample

That's it, it should work fine!

Comment: Hi danakim. I was not clear I think, regarding what I mean by endpoints. I have just one server. The endpoints I mention, all point to the same server. I do not have many backend servers. What I want ideally, is to group these endpoints. Hope it's more clear now

Comment: Hi Thomas. Sorry, I am still not sure what you mean by endpoint. So you have just one server and an endpoint is a URI on that server? Or a different port on that server? So you have http://backend:8080/banner/save ; http://backend:8080/banner/save1 and so on? Or you have http://backend:8080 ; http://backend:8081 and so on?

Comment: Hi. I have just one server. By endpoints I mean URIs (should have used URI instead of endpoint). So I have 1 backend server (backend:8080) and many different URIs, like /banner/save, /image/upload, /video/save etc.

Comment: Understood now. Then I am afraid you might have to define each URI separately. I wouldn't take my word for it and I would check out the documentation a bit more, but I am 90% sure you can not do it.